# Format billing phone number on WooCommerce account to add space between code and number

Tags: php, woocommerce, format

I want to force the phone number on the woocommerce registration field to be like 01234 567890 instead of 01234567890 so it adds a space after the 5th number.

I need the same for the mobile number too.

I've tried a few variations of answers that I found before and added to my functions.php file but it either didn't work or bust my site.

Comment: Could you post the code you've got?

Comment: I've used the code below as was the nearest I could get but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive numbers in different formats you could start replacing all non-digits and then add a space after 5 digits. Here is an example of a function:

```
function formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber){
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phoneNumber); //Replacing non-digits.
    $phoneNumber = substr_replace($phoneNumber, ' ', 5, 0); //Adding space after 5 digits.
    return $phoneNumber;
}
```

Try the code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05bdf751a8db823044767261a1e4c451f89dcfd4).

If you want to format input fields you can do it with help of JavaScript, in this case with jQuery which is bundled with WordPress.

```
$("#formInput").keyup(function(){
  input = $("#formInput").val();
  input = input.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Replacing non digits
  if(input.length > 5){ //Adding space if string is larger than 5.
    input = [input.slice(0, 5), " ", input.slice(5)].join('');
  }
  $("#formInput").val(input);
})
```

Try the code [here](https://codepen.io/mikaelwallgren/pen/dyYZvNy)

Comment: That's perfect - works a treat. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: OK, tried this but it had no effect on the phone number I input?

Comment: Do you mean the input field where the user input their phone number? In that case, you have to implement logic on the front end. I updated my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: That works great in your example - exactly as I want. However, how do I add it to the child theme in Wordpress. I usually add to the functions file but it's javascript. Could I use this in my functions file:
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { ?>
 <script>
  ( function( $ ) {
   'use strict';
   $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
    // Your custom code here
   } );
  } ( jQuery ) );
 </script>
<?php } );

but what would the final code look like?

Thanks.